# Listview scrolling down issue

Tags: android, listview, scroll

after some research that did not result, I came here to ask for a little help.

Here is my issue :

A Listview which display a list of applications (name and icon) installed on my device.
Applications are displayed but when I scroll, elements overlap.

Here is my onCreate (activity) :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        //
        final ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm
            .queryIntentActivities(intent,
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

        ApplicationsAdapter adapter = new ApplicationsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.id.lv_home, list, pm);


        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_home);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Here is my custom adapter :

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderListViewHome holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolderListViewHome(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolderListViewHome) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final String text = mList.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo
            .loadLabel(mPm).toString();

    holder.applicationName = holder.getApplicationName();

    holder.applicationName.setText(text);

    final Drawable drawable = mList.get(position).activityInfo.applicationInfo
            .loadIcon(mPm);

    holder.applicationIcon = holder.getApplicationIcon();

    holder.applicationIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable);

    return convertView;
}
```

I wanted to show you a picture but I do not have the required reputation, the elements simply overlaps when scrolling down.

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ViewHolder is static.  Remove the holder.applicationIcon = holder.getApplicationIcon() and similar calls.  Just use holder.applicationIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable) -- same advice for your text view.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for answering. My ViewHolder isn't static, I tried to make it static and call my attributes in a static way but nothing changed, elements are still overlapsing each other.